# How to persist data and schema when a Cassandra Container is deleted

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I create a Cassandra Container, run it, create schema and add data to it. When I later stop the Container and delete it and create a new one from the image, the previously created schema and data is lost.

Can I/How can I persist data and schema such that whenever a container is created from an image, it picks existing schema and data?

Do would I have to recreate the schema and add data?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I used -v option to mount an external directory (external outside the container).

Eg.

For container 1 (node1)

```
docker run  -v C:\...\dockertest\dockerdata\cassandra1:/var/lib/cassandra --network cassandra-net -p 9042:9042 --name cassandra1 cassandra_image_id
```

For container 2 (node2)-

```
docker run  -v C:\...\dockertest\dockerdata\cassandra2:/var/lib/cassandra --network cassandra-net --name cassandra2  -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=cassandra1 cassandra_image_id
```

If running both containers on the same machine, the external directory must be different for each node/container